# Route audio via speaker when headphone plugged it

Tags: android, audio, media

How we can route audio output via speaker even when the headset is plugged in?

My code:

```
    if(audioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn())
    {
        audioManager.setWiredHeadsetOn(false);
        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true); 
        audioManager.setRouting(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL, AudioManager.ROUTE_SPEAKER, AudioManager.ROUTE_ALL);  
        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL); 

    }
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />` to your AndroidManifest.xml ?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS

Answer (score 1):

The method [`AudioManager.setRouting()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setRouting%28int,%20int,%20int%29) is depreciated.

From the Javadoc:

> Do not set audio routing directly, use [`setSpeakerphoneOn()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setSpeakerphoneOn%28boolean%29), [`setBluetoothScoOn()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setBluetoothScoOn%28boolean%29) methods instead.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need to  audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL) or MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION;